# jasmine test case for Restangular within a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, restangular

How to write jasmine test for Rectangular for a scenario like as shown below

**script**

```
$scope.allEmployees = [{
            visible: true,
            empId: "EMP148"
 }];

$scope.employeeDocuments = {  "EMP148": [{
                                        "empId": "EMP148",
                                        "department": "Sales",
                                        "firstName": "Manu",
                                        "lastName": "Mathew",
                                        "place": "Kolkata"
                                        }]
                           };

var employeesCopy = angular.copy($scope.allEmployees);
$scope.allEmployees.push({visible: true, empId: "EMP489"});  

$scope.addEmployees = function (employeesCopy) {
    var newEmployee = {visible: true, empId: "EMP489"};
    var emplyeeList = {
        employees: $scope.allEmployees,
        newEmployee: newEmployee
    };
    Restangular.all('emp/getEmployees').post(emplyeeList).then(function (employees) {
        if (!_.isEmpty(employees[emplyeeList.newEmployee.empId])) {
            if ($scope.employeeDocuments.hasOwnProperty(emplyeeList.newEmployee.empId)) {
                delete $scope.employeeDocuments[emplyeeList.newEmployee.empId];
            }
            $scope.employeeDocuments[emplyeeList.newEmployee.empId] = employees[emplyeeList.newEmployee.empId];
            setMyEmployees(true);
            $scope.flag = true;
            console.log("success");
        } else {
            $scope.employeeDocuments = employeesCopy;
            console.log("no documents");
        }
        $scope.flag = false;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("failed");
        $scope.flag = false;
    });
};

$scope.addEmployees(employeesCopy);
setMyEmployees = function (flag)
{
    // other implementation
};
```

I have wrote a test cases like as shown below, but i am getting exception like `spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for all()`

**test case**

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q1d2qfay/2/)** -  contains the full logic as well as the test cases

```
describe('Testing Controllers', function() {
    describe('Testing EmployeeController Controller', function() {
        var EmployeeController, $scope, $httpBackend, Restangular;

        beforeEach(function() {
           module('emp');
        }); 

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $filter, $injector, Restangular, $httpBackend) {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            Restangular = $injector.get("Restangular");
            EmployeeController = $controller('EmployeeController ', {
                $rootScope: $rootScope,
                $scope: $scope,
                $filter: $filter
            });
        }));

        it('should add new employees when addEmployees() is called', inject(function($httpBackend)
        {
           $scope.allEmployees = [{
                                    visible: true,
                                    empId: "EMP148"
                              }];

           $scope.employeeDocuments = {  "EMP148": [{
                                            "empId": "EMP148",
                                            "department": "Sales",
                                            "firstName": "Manu",
                                            "lastName": "Mathew",
                                            "place": "Kolkata"
                                            }]
                                   };

           var employeesCopy = angular.copy($scope.allEmployees);

           spyOn(Restangular, 'all').andCallThrough();

           var newEmployee = {visible: true, empId: "EMP489"};
           var emplyeeList = {
                employees: $scope.allEmployees,
                newEmployee: newEmployee
           };

           var mockToReturn = {
                "EMP489": [{
                "empId": "EMP489",
                "department": "Sales",
                "firstName": "Ram",
                "lastName": "Mohan",
                "place": "Delhi"
                }]
            };
            $scope.addEmployees(employeesCopy);
            $httpBackend.expectPOST('emp/getEmployees',emplyeeList).respond(mockToReturn);
            expect(Restangular.all).toHaveBeenCalledWith('emp/getEmployees');
            expect(setMyEmployees(true)).toHaveBeenCalled();

        }));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have multiples problem :

First, to answer your question to use toHavebeenCalled you have to create a spy first.

What I would do is put setMyEmployees at the scope level, and then add a spy on the scope

```
spyOn($scope);
```

But you have a test that make an asyncronous request, so your test case will fail because it will reach the end before the asynchronous request succeed.

With jasmine 2 you can use done() for asynchonous test :

```
it('should add new employees when addEmployees() is called', function(done) 
{
    //call when asyncronous operation is finish
    done();
}
```

But with the way you've created your function, you can't use done.
You will have to have a callback block in your method or a promise

Callback :

```
$scope.addEmployees = function(employeesCopy, success, failure)
{
    //code
    Restangular.all('user/getEmployees').post(emplyeeList).then(function(employees)
    {
        if (!_.isEmpty(employees[emplyeeList.employeeId]))
        {
           // code
        }
        else
        {
            // code
        }
        success();
        $scope.flag = false;
    }, function(error)
    {
        failure();
        $scope.flag = false;
    });
};
```

Note the toHaveBeenCall syntax

```
it('should add new employees when addEmployees() is called', function(done) 
{
var employeesCopy = {
    firstName: "Manu",
    lastName: "Sam"
};

spyOn($scope);

$scope.addEmployees(employeesCopy, function(){

    done();

});

expect($scope.setMyEmployees).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
});
```

I would prefer a promise syntax :

```
$scope.addEmployees = function(employeesCopy, defer)
{
    //code
    Restangular.all('user/getEmployees').post(emplyeeList).then(function(employees)
    {
        if (!_.isEmpty(employees[emplyeeList.employeeId]))
        {
           // code
        }
        else
        {
            // code
        }
        defer.resolve();
        $scope.flag = false;
    }, function(error)
    {
        defer.reject();
        $scope.flag = false;
    });
};


it('should add new employees when addEmployees() is called', function(done) 
{
var employeesCopy = {
    firstName: "Manu",
    lastName: "Sam"
};

spyOn($scope);

var defer = $q.defer;
defer.promise.then(function(){

    console.log("success");
    done();
}, function (){
    done();
    console.log("error");
});

$scope.addEmployees(employeesCopy, defer);

expect($scope.setMyEmployees).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
});
```

The last problem you will have is to mock the network call if you want your test to be truly unitary (else you'r also testing the backend answer, that could be what you want)
If you want to mock the call you should look at $httpBackend, this blog post seems to have more informations : https://ath3nd.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/15/ (not mine)

EDIT, add dependancy to test, before your it(), use a beforeEach :

```
var myService, Restangular;
    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function($injector) {
            myService = $injector.get('MyService');//exemple service
            Restangular = $injector.get("Restangular");
        });
    });
```

EDIT 2 :

Ok I havn't explain it correctly, try :

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $filter, $injector, _Restangular_, _$httpBackend_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        Restangular = _Restangular_;
        EmployeeController = $controller('EmployeeController ', {
            $rootScope: $rootScope,
            $scope: $scope,
            $filter: $filter
        });
    }));
```

Comment: actually  i need to mock and show the restangular stuff in test case

Comment: i have updated my answer with the stuffs which you have give, but now getting `<failure type="">Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for all()`

Comment: Try to Add Restangular in your inject ?

Comment: now i am getting `<failure type="">TypeError: &apos;undefined&apos; is not a function (evaluating &apos;spyOn(Restangular,&apos;all&apos;).andCallThrough()&apos;)`

Comment: Something is undefined, maybe Restangular, I will add an Edit to my post to show how to add dependancy

Comment: i have inject Retsnagular like as you said now i am getting `Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for all()`

Comment: It really looks like a configuration problem, can you put your entire test file in the question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65373/discussion-between-alex-man-and-boris-charpentier).

Comment: i have given 50 bounty for this question...also i have made a mockup jsfiddle to show the issue http://jsfiddle.net/q1d2qfay/2/ ....can you help me with this

Comment: I'm currently creating a project recreating your case to answer.

Comment: have you seen my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q1d2qfay/2/  you have make the changes over there itself right

Comment: I've updated it, there where several problem with $controller, now I can't get the restangular promise to be resolve but it's much closer than before